# Apollo Typescript Query with no Variables and Not all codes return a value error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, apollo

below is my codes. i am trying to add types to my code. I am facing the following 2 issues...

1. Not all code paths return a value
2. As it is a query that takes no variables, i have no variables to input into my query

what i am unsure about is how should I add a ts-lint rule into my react code to disable the message 'not all code paths return a value'

and also, if i use GetTweets_getTweets as second type declaration, is it correct? as there are no variables

below are my query and type codes. thanks

```
   <Query<GetTweets, GetTweets_getTweets> query={GET_TWEETS}>
          {({ data, loading, error }) => {
            if (loading) {
              return <div>Loading...</div>;
            }
            if (error) {
              return <div>{error.message}</div>;
            }
            if (data) {
              return data.getTweets.map((el: any) => (
                <p key={el._id}>{el.text}</p>
              ));
            }
          }}
        </Query>

export interface GetTweets_getTweets_comments {
  __typename: "Comment";
  _id: string;
  text: string;
}

export interface GetTweets_getTweets {
  __typename: "Tweet";
  _id: string;
  text: string;
  createdAt: any;
  comments: GetTweets_getTweets_comments[];
}

export interface GetTweets {
  getTweets: GetTweets_getTweets[];
}
```